# How can I return a master record from 3 possible child record values, where the master record MUST contain all 3 child values

Tags: sql, sql-server

The Setup:

Ill try to explain this as best as possible.  I have a master table that contains account information. I have a child table that contains transaction information about the the account.  Each transaction has a transaction code.  "P", "I", "X" and others...  For this particular issue, im only concerned with P,I and X though.  I need to query the data where it returns the master record ONLY where there is a P I AND X record.  (has to have ALL three).
I've tried creating views to group things then query against the view, but I'm just not grasping the way to check if all three criteria are met in SQL.

The Question:

How can I join 2 tables where I can  specify that the matches contain at least all three child record types?(im on a REALLY old version of MSSQL server, however I can transfer the data to mysql or oracle if this task is more easily done on either of those platforms)

The expected output would be a single master record for each instance that meets the criteria of containing at least one of each P, I and X transaction type of child table.

EDIT:
TEST DATA: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/dde45

Comment: Here is a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One method is to use aggregation and `having`:

```
select c.parentid
from child c
where c.code in ('P', 'I', 'X')
group by c.parentid
having count(distinct c.code) = 3;
```